# "contact" SQL table: what is it for and where do I edit it?

Tags: database

We are running a site with the Hotel Diamond theme. Today we received a bounced email: apparently, someone had tried using the contact form in the site to send us a message, and the system had tried sending it to "test@localhost.com".

Now, the Hotel Diamond theme has an option to configure the email for the contact page, but it is correctly configured (i.e., it's NOT "test@localhost.com"). So I decided to look for that address in the raw SQL dump of my site, and I found this:

```
INSERT INTO `contact` (`cid`, `category`, `recipients`, `reply`, `weight`, `selected`) VALUES
(1, 'Website feedback', 'test@localhost.com', '', 0, 1);
```

My question is: where do I edit that in the admin pages? And why is Drupal using this entry to send contact email, instead of the address we had configured in the Hotel Diamond config page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `admin/structure/contact/edit/1` and change Recipients email address to whatever you want.